Does std::future keep std::async lambda alive after execution?
For this example:
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
struct S {
  std::string mName = "";
};

std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
int main(){
  {
    auto s = std::make_shared<S>();
    futures.emplace_back(std::async([s2=s]{}));
  }
  // will s2 be alive here assuming the async execution is done?
}

will the stored future keep the lambda alive or will that lambda and its by-value captures get destroyed after the async execution is finished? ChatGPT says 'yes' it will keep lambda alive but there is no reference.

s goes out of scope, it can't be alive at the commented line.

@3CxEZiVlQ They are asking about the s that is the lambda stored in the global future object. Not the block scope s object.

It would be weird for the future to destroy the function object earlier than its own destruction.  I would expect the function to be part of the shared state and that doesn't get destroyed until the last reference is.

Seems like the answer is yes

I don't think the Standard says anything about it, and other than having a side effect in ~S there isn't any way to make use of it. So how are you going to use it in practice? And what do you mean after execution? -- when the future becomes ready?

gcc at least, doesn't destroy the capture until you get result from the future: https://godbolt.org/z/chq4cqraK

std::futures returned by std::async are blocking. So the destruction of futures will synchronize with the treads ending. And the lambda will be alive for as long as the thread needs it, thus also its capture by value variables will be alive too. (So in fact without std::jthread futures are a way of synchronizing with a thread in an RAII manner)

@3CxEZiVlQ Edited question so that the capture is now called s2, which should make things clearer.

@NathanOliver The function object in an async can only be invoked once.  It makes a lot  of sense to clean it up as soon as it is finished; why hold resources that are guaranteed to be never used again?  If I was writing the spec for std future, I'd make it destroy the callable once the callable is finished, and just persist the return value (or exception).  That is, if I remembered to specify this at all!

muaz, do you want to know what happens in practice, or what does the standard guarantee?  I suspect that the standard under specifies this, but I am not certain.

@Yakk - Adam Nevraumont -- the question isn't well formulated. There are two points at which the future can dispose of callable. First, when shared state becomes ready, and second, when the value is retrieved from the shared state. Compilers do the latter, though nothing prevents them from doing the former: https://godbolt.org/z/Gjxo9x6hz

@Gene If you add in a shared future to your code (like this), the callable lifetime is now extended past .get() ... for no good reason really.  I mean, the reason is that the shared state internal object with the return value also holds the callable, but there isn't a reason for those two to share lifetime really.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am actually concerned of what the standard says, or at least both gcc and msvc, I looked over the standard and found nothing, but not sure whether I missed something.

The declaration of std::async that you are using is according to [futures.async]:
template<class F, class... Args>
  [[nodiscard]] future<invoke_result_t<decay_t<F>, decay_t<Args>...>>
    async(F&& f, Args&&... args);

First of all, the original lambda object passed for f is a temporary object that will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression
futures.emplace_back(std::async([s2=s]{}))

and its capture s2 with it. However, std::async will have moved from the lambda into the actual object that will be invoked. This copy is constructed as if by auto(std::forward<F>(f)) (see below). Your question is probably when this object will be destroyed, taking the last reference to the S object with it.
When you don't give any launch policy argument to std::async it defaults to std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred, which means that the implementation can choose either of the two policies. See [futures.async]/3.
If the implementation chooses std::launch::async, then it shall behave as if starting a thread that executes ([futures.async]/3.1):
invoke(auto(std​::​forward<F>(f)), auto(std​::​forward<Args>(args))...)

In this case the copy of the callable is a temporary object in this expression. It will be destroyed in the thread invoking the callable once it returns.
If the implementation chooses std::launch::deferred, then it shall store a copy g of f initialized by auto(std​::​forward<F>(f)) in the shared state of the std::future, and similarly copies xyz... of args... initialized by auto(std::forward<Args>(args)).... When the deferred function is invoked, it shall execute
invoke(std​::​move(g), std​::​move(xyz)...)

See [futures.async]/3.2.
Here the destruction of the copy of f is not part of the expression or the deferred invocation of the function.
[futures.async]/3.2 doesn't specify further when these objects are going to be destroyed.
I think, given that [futures.async]/3.2 is clearly stating when and how the copy of f is stored in the shared state and does neither say that it is replaced or released, the implementation shouldn't destroy it just because it is not needed any more after the deferred invocation finishes.
std::future::wait also doesn't specify that it releases shared state of the future, so it itself also shouldn't destroy g.
On the other hand std::future::get is specified to release all shared state and so should destroy g.
Moving the std::future into futures will also move the state of g, making another copy of the lambda, but moving the ownership of the S object by s2 again to the new copy.
So, for your specific example, I think it is unspecified whether or not the S object will still be alive at the commented line. It depends on which policy the implementation chooses: If it chooses launch::async, then it will be destroyed, or rather its destruction will happen in the other thread unsynchronized with reaching the comment line. If it chooses launch::deferred, then it will not be destroyed (because you didn't call any member function on std::future that will release its state).

+1 and accepted because it goes hand by hand with the standard. However, for me for both gcc and msvc it never gets destroyed unless get is called on the returned future whether async or deferred policies are applied, btw wait does not clean the shared state.

@muaz If (only) async policy is used, then I think that would be a library bug. And wait does not clear the state as I said, yes.
